# How to maintain Body formatting for MS Graph email that is formatted for Javascript on the frontend?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, vuetify.js

On my front end I am using Vuetify which is a VueJS UI framework which uses a combobox for the body of the email input. The user can edit it and what not. I initially prefil it with predicted text of this form:

```
textModel = "To whom it may concern, \n\n" +
"We are writing to you about blah blah blah. \n\n" +
"Thank You"
```

This data is then sent to the backend API via [FormData] and binding it to a model as it is apart of a larging email Model (subject, recipients, etc). However, for my email interface I use the following to assign the body to the message object:

```
            var message = new Message
        {
            Subject = email.Subject,
            Body = new ItemBody
            {
                ContentType = Microsoft.Graph.BodyType.Html,
                Content = email.Body,
            },

            ToRecipients = ToRec,
            CcRecipients = CcRec,
            BccRecipients = BccRec,
            Attachments = attachments,
        };
```

When I send the email via MS Graph API and I receive the email the body is formatted as a single line so the "\n" is doing nothing. How would I account for new lines in this manner to use on the front end and backend? Do I have to do a find and replace on the body string and replace with a br tags in html?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your trying to send in

```
textModel = "To whom it may concern, \n\n" +
"We are writing to you about blah blah blah. \n\n" +
"Thank You"
```

is formatted text but in

```
            Body = new ItemBody
        {
            ContentType = Microsoft.Graph.BodyType.Html,
            Content = email.Body,
        },
```

your saying the body is Html if you want to send a Text body you should make it

```
        Body = new ItemBody
        {
            ContentType = Microsoft.Graph.BodyType.Text,
            Content = email.Body,
        },
```

or format your text as html instead eg

```
textModel = "To whom it may concern, <br>" +
"We are writing to you about blah blah blah. <br><br>" +
"Thank You<br>"
```

Comment: Wow I am dumb. I thought about trying text and didnt because i figured that wouldnt work.